# JavaScript - Accessing Different Variables from Different Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, select

I have three different select boxes that users can choose from.  I need to access the values of all three selections at once and can't figure out how to do it.  Let me explain what I mean with an example:

```
<select id="hue">
// Options
</select>

<select id="sat">
// Options
</select>

<select id="lig">
// Options
</select>
```

Now, to access the choice of each select box I use the following code:

```
$('#hue').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    hueVal = $(this).val();
    return hueVal;
})

$('#sat').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    satVal = $(this).val();
    return satVal;
})

$('#lig').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    ligVal = $(this).val();
    return ligVal;
})
```

Now, what I want to do is get access to the three returned values (hueVal, satVal and ligVal) at the same time in a new jquery call - like follows:

```
$('#header').css('background-color', hsl(hueVal+','+satVal+','+ligVal));
```

The problem is, since each value  is within a function I don't know how to get access to all three of them at once outside of their respective functions.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: The JS does not make much sense. `.val()` returns a string, you're attaching event handlers to strings !? You might as well setup a http://jsfiddle.net with a minimum demo of your scenario after fixing those issues, in case you don't get a satisfactory answer until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var hue = $('#hue').val(),
        sat = $('#sat').val(),
        lig = $('#lig').val();

    $('#header').css('background-color', 'hsl('+ hue +','+ sat +','+ lig +')');
}).trigger('change');
```

edit: the value for background-color needs to be a full string

Answer (score 3):

Consider declaring global variables, outside the functions:

```
var hueVal;
var satVal;
var ligVal;

$('#hue').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    hueVal = $(this).val();
    return hueVal;
})

$('#sat').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    satVal = $(this).val();
    return satVal;
})

$('#lig').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    ligVal = $(this).val();
    return ligVal;
})

$('#header').css('background-color', hsl(hueVal+','+satVal+','+ligVal);
```

Comment: Currently variables are _global_.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables outside of the functions, then modify the variables inside the functions (returning the values is useless in this context):

```
var hueVal,
    satVal,
    ligVal;

$('#hue').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    hueVal = $(this).val();
});

$('#sat').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    satVal = $(this).val();
});

$('#lig').filter(':selected').val().change(function(){
    ligVal = $(this).val();
});
```

You can then do what you'd like with them, i.e.:

```
$('#header').css('background-color', hsl(hueVal+','+satVal+','+ligVal);
```

You might also want to read up on [scope](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object to manage these values.

```
var color = {
    hue: $('#hue').val(),
    sat: $('#sat').val(),
    lig: $('#lig').val()
};

$('#hue,#sat,#lig').change(function() {
   color[this.id] = $(this).val();
   $('#header').css('background-color', 'hsl('+color.hue+','+color.sat+','+color.lig+')');
});
```

***Note:***

- Use `.val()` could get the selected value of the select.
- `hsl` is css expression, it also need to be a string.